# Resizing CodeMirror editor with CSS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, resize, height, codemirror

I have been trying to change the width and height of my Codemirror editor using CSS but it does not seem to have any effect.

```
.CodeMirror {
   width: 500px;
   height: 1000px;
}
```

Instead of resizing accordingly it remains at a height of 300px and full width.
Nevertheless I am still able to set width and height via code: `editor.setSize(500, 1000);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u try !important?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and made sure to refresh the tab.

Comment: did you try setting the option "viewportMargin: Infinity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to import your own CSS file after the default stylesheets of Codemirror. Otherwise the defaults do not get overridden properly. Simply import your stylesheet last.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried.

```
.CodeMirror {
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Try using percentages. 
Also CodeMirror docs specifically say you should use width: auto and height: auto to auto scale. just fyi.

Comment: Using this the width gets halved but the height is still the same.

Comment: Now it got even smaller but the height is still the same.